# See function for symbol search in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, search, visual-studio-2005

I'm currently editing a good sized class in C# that has a ton of properties, many of which I suspect are just local variables used by a single function. Hence I'm in a mood for some refactoring.

Is there a way to customise the search results on a "Find Symbol" search to give more information, like the function where a symbol appears (and I'm guessing others would be nice, like namespace and class)?

Comment: Of course, I'm not completely reckless, I know a variable can be stored for later use. But this gem I found... it's a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to customize the results of the Find Symbol dialog.